# Licensing: source code vs. production code in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, licensing, source-code

For commercial and licensing purposes, what is the correct wording for differentiating JavaScript source code (written by the programmer and including comments) from the minified version used in production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll generally find it is called a **debug build** (example: [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/index.html)), or **development build/version** (example: [BackboneJS](http://backbonejs.org/)), or "uncompressed build" (example: [JQuery](http://jquery.com/download/)).

I think that all three variants are clear to anyone downloading them.

Comment: Thanks! And how would you call the production/minified version?

Comment: well, either "production" or "minified" build/version :-) Nothing wrong with that